# Multiple settings files with Google App Engine project

Tags: python, django, git, google-app-engine

#### A note before the question

We generally have a settings.py file and a local_settings.py file in standard Django project layouts.

- **settings.py**: for production settings
- **local_settings.py**: for local settings that override production settings when running the project locally

The local_settings.py file is added to .gitignore to avoid being pushed into production via git push.

#### The question

In appengine when we push the application using:

```
appcfg.py update exampleproject
```

The local_settings.py file also gets pushed up even though it has been added to .gitignore.
At first adding the following lines to app.yaml looks like a possible solution:

```
skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?local_settings.py
```

These lines tell app engine to ignore the local_settings.py file.

But, then we face another problem ->

**The local_settings.py file is totally excluded.** ie. It is not even used when running the application locally along with dev_appserver.py.

Is there any good solution that can help define multiple settings files in a Google App Engine based Django project?

Comment: How are you importing the local_settings file? Our projects follow a similar concept but don't have an issue as you described.

Comment: The following lines at the end of the settings.py file are used for importing my local_settings.

try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass

Comment: That is very odd. Are you sure an import error isn't occurring if you were to remove the try catch for debugging?